# Excel VBA - Copy/Paste range from one sheet to all proceeding sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

First time asking a question so please let me know if I'm missing anything.

I found this code from another SO post. I'm trying to copy the entire worksheet from "DNU" into each proceeding worksheet. The issue I'm having is that this will paste values but I'm looking to do a regular paste to keep the formatting and formulas. I've tried changing from the "Value" to Copy and Paste but this end up in an error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:
~

```
Dim wsVar As Worksheet

Dim i as Integer
For i = 6 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:y200").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DNU").Range("A1:Y200").Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DNU").Range("A1:Y200").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1")`

Comment: @BigBen Yes, thanks) Fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Copy() method of Range object

```
Dim wsVar As Worksheet
Dim i as Integer
With ThisWorkbook
    For i = 6 to .Worksheets.Count
        .Worksheets("DNU").Range("A1:Y200").Copy destination:=.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200")
    Next 
End With
```

Comment: Running into another issue where the column widths in the new worksheets are not the same as the "DNU" worksheet. Is there a way to copy the width formatting?

Comment: For i = 6 To .Worksheets.Count
        .Worksheets("DNU").Range("A1:Y200").Copy
        .Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        .Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Next

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason why the groupings from "DNU" wouldn't be saved into the new worksheets? Is there a way around this or do they need to be regrouped in each worksheet?

Comment: @Hiimtroymcclure, I don't use groups and hence can't give you help on that. But if my answer solved your original question you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you