# Copy and Paste Formula from a sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge multiple sheets into one single sheet using Excel VBA.
I followed the codes in this [website](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm) There is a function called `Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()`
It gets the first and last row in each sheet, and paste the values at the end of the merged sheet.

```
'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
 StartRow = 2
 Last = LastRow(DestSh)
 shLast = LastRow(sh)
 Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
```

It copies the cell `values` using the following code:

```
CopyRng.Copy
With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

This code only copy the `values`. Since there are `formulas` in the cells, I changed this part to :

```
CopyRng.Copy
With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

As an alternative I tried this code as well:

```
CopyRng.Copy DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
```

Or the code in the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085612/excel-vba-copy-paste-range-from-one-sheet-to-all-proceeding-sheets)

All of these three solutions, copy the `formulas` with an `extra text` (which I assume it is a reference to the original sheets).
for example the formula in the original sheet is:

```
=(IF([@[Actual Date]]="",[@[Forecast
Date]],[@[Actual Date]]))+[@[Shipping 
(days) ]]*2
```

Where "Forecast Date" "Actual Date", and "Shipping (days)" are column names (Table headers)

And after the merge, it will be:

```
=(IF(_PMTemplate333574[@[Actual Date]]="",_PMTemplate333574[@[Forecast 
Date]],_PMTemplate333574[@[Actual Date]]))+_PMTemplate333574[@[Shipping 
(days) ]]*2
```

For each sheet this reference number (`_PMTemplate333574`) is different, and for some sheets it returns an error.
I tried to manually delete this reference, but it's time consuming. I was wondering what is it? and how can it be removed?

Comment: What notation style are you using for your formula? It looks like an R1C1 notation, but there should be `!` to indicate a sheet name. I also don't know why there is an `@`. So it likely isn't actually R1C1 notation.

Comment: @Toddleson I'm not sure either. can you help me out to remove this extra text from formula? for example search for anything that start with "_PMT" and end with a number, replace with empty string? I wrote this code `Worksheets(1).Range("A3:A4").Replace What:="_PMTemplate333574", Replacement:="" ` and it works fine, but need to make it dynamic since there's unique number for each sheet.

Comment: In Excel's Find & Replace, you can use the wildcard "\*" to mean "anything". So if you say Find "_PMT\*", it means find anything that starts with "_PMT". But this would fix the symptom and not the cause. The root issue is why your formulas generate this weird address when copied and pasted. I have no answer to that.

Comment: @Toddleson I figured that's the Table Name. Each sheet is basically a table with header, and each table has a name. And after merging the sheets, the formulas use the table name!